# Security differences between Passive and Active RFID tags

Tags: physical, rfid

Most people are aware there are two types of RFID tags, active tags (ones that contain a power source of some kind) and passive tags (ones that are powered by the RF field).

I'd like to know if choosing one type or the other provides a security advantage? Does the ability to power passive tags only via RF field mean that it is harder to implement secure designs? Are there any other security concerns I should consider when choosing RFID systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Network bandwidth is a [scarce resource in RFID protocols](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9582/validating-data-on-rfid-chip-that-has-rsa-signatures-and-sha1-hash-values).

Active tags have a double edge sword when it comes to security.  For one they are able to support more bandwidth and therefore larger key sizes.  The "problem" is that active tags also have a longer range,  and there for an attacker further away is able to obtain a challenge response. Passive tags have a shorter range,  and are limited in the cryptographic algorithms they are able to use...

So what is your implantation?  Ideally you would have a faraday cage to protect your active tags when they are not in use.